# WordPress URL rewrite rule for a template?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have built website for real estate with a fairly typical property search functionality that returns property listings on a property search page.

When a visitor clicks on a listing in the search results, I need to pass the property's ID to a WP page "*property-detail*" (that calls a template called *template-propertydetail.php*) which then uses the ID to pull property data from a database.

So what I need is for a clicked link like:

*https://example.com/property-detail/?mlsid=12345*

to be rewritten to this when the page displays:

*https://example.com/property-detail/12345*

UPDATE
I have implemented the code suggested by Moishy below in functions.php and flushed rules and cache but the url does not rewrite.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^property-detail/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?template_page=property_detail&mlsid=$matches[1]',
        'top', 'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "template_page";
    $vars[] = "mlsid";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

function include_custom_template($template){
    if(get_query_var('template_page') && get_query_var('template_page') === 'property_detail'){
        $template = get_template_directory() ."/templates/template-propertydetail.php";
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'include_custom_template');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^property-detail/([^/]*)/?', 
        'index.php?template_page=property_detail&mlsid=$matches[1]', 'top',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "template_page";
    $vars[] = "mlsid";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

and then you can pull the id in the template page:

```
get_query_var('mlsid')
```

and to pull your custom template:

```
function include_custom_template($template){


    if(get_query_var('template_page') && get_query_var('template_page') === 'property_detail'){
        $template = get_template_directory() ."YOUR_TEMPLATE_FILE";
    }
    
    return $template;
      
}

add_filter('template_include', 'include_custom_template');
```

**Make sure to flush your cache and rewrite rules after adding it** by going to Settings > Permalinks and hit 'Save Changes'

Comment: I have added all the above to functions.php, flushed the rules, but nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry I didnt fix your regex, I updated the answer